# Go back to original repository in homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I'm using homebrew and had to tap a new repository since my original repository doesn't have a formula I need. Now, I have installed what I need, I want to go back to my original repository, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can type in the following:

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew
```

to go back.

Comment: The problem is I don't know the name of the original <old> repository. :(

Comment: @monodev Was it the default?

Comment: Yes. default one with fresh install.

Comment: @monodev I have changed it.